# I need help translating a signed photo book

Tags: translation, handwriting

I bought a first edition of a photo book by Shiraishi Chieko and it looks as though it has been signed in pencil on the front page. The first character may be slightly smudged because I rubbed it to see if it was printed or in pencil.
I have tried to translate it [picture of the signed book] online but I am having no luck.

Please can anyone tell me what it says.

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCScq.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCScq.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YAml.jpg)

Comment: I'm very sorry, but requests for translation and transcription are not the purpose of this forum and should be asked somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It just spells her name, Shiraishi Chieko 白石ちえこ